# I get a LoadError when trying to about anything with a new Ruby install on Windows

Tags: ruby

I installed Ruby on Windows via RubyInstaller, with the associated DevKit.

I'm trying to run various scripts (mainly Jekyll), and I'm getting all sorts of errors about paths.  For instance:

```
...cannot load such file -- redcarpet.so (LoadError)
```

Or:

```
...cannot load such file -- 2.0/redcloth_scan (LoadError)
```

Specifically, in both those cases, I'm trying to run "redcloth.bat" and "redcarpet.bat" in the bin directory of the Ruby directory.

I feel like I'm missing something basic with paths. Note that this has never worked -- I installed the RubyInstaller, then the DevKit, then the Jekyll gem...and this is what happened.

Is there something basic about this installation that I failed to set?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the RedCloth side of this error today.

We started with this error

[How to install RedCloth on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290868/how-to-install-redcloth-on-windows)

What we found was we had installed the mswin32 version of RedCloth, we first got the no such file to load.

We then went to our

C:\ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-mswin32

Directory , added the 2.0 file and copied the redcloth_scan.so file into the 2.0 directory.

We started getting another error that was similar.

We decided we would just uninstall the precompiled version of the gem, and start with the normal RedCloth-2.4.9.gem to be compiled locally with devkit.

Once this was installed, we again went to the lib dir for the gem.

CD   C:/ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-2.4.9/lib

We created a 2.0 directory

We then copied the file redcloth_scan.so file into the 2.0 directory and we no longer had the error.  The server came up fine and we